# What is meant by “replace equals by equals”

Tags: haskell

I'm Haskell newbie and reading :

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/01-intro.html

It states "In Haskell one can always “replace equals by equals”, just like you learned in algebra class.". What is meant by this and what are its advantages ?

I don't recall learning this in algebra but perhaps I do not recognise the terminology.

Comment: It's just what you think.  If an expression `e1` is equal to an expression `e2`, then you can replace `e1` with `e2` inside any expression.  A simple example might be `1 + 1`, which could easily be replaced by `2`, or `(\x. y) z` with `y` inside the expression `(\x. x) ((\x. y) z)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that if you know that `A` (an expression) is equal to `B` (another expression), then you may always replace `A` for `B` in any expression involving `A`, and vice-versa.

For instance, we know that `even = not . odd`. Therefore

```
   filter even
= 
   filter (not . odd)
```

On the other hand, we know that `odd` satisfies the following equation

```
 odd = (1 ==) . (`mod` 2)
```

As such, we also know that

```
   filter even
 =
   filter (not . odd)
 =
   filter (not . (1 ==) . (`mod` 2))
```

Moreover, you know that `mod 2` always returns `0` or `1`. So, by case analysis, the following is valid.

```
   not . (1 ==)
= 
   (0 ==)
```

Therefore, we can also say

```
  filter even
= 
  filter ((0 ==) . (`mod` 2))
```

The advantage of being able to *replace equals by equals* is to design a program by massaging equation after equation until a suitable definition is found, like in typical *solve for x* kind of problems of Algebra.

Answer (score 4):

In its simplest form, substituting "equals by equals" means replacing a defined identifier with its definition. For instance

```
let x = f 1 in x + x
```

can be equivalently written as

```
f 1 + f 1
```

in the sense that the result will be the same. In GHC, you can expect the second one to re-compute `f 1` twice, possibly degrading performance, but the result of the sum is the same.

In impure languages, such as Ocaml, the two snippets above are instead *not* equivalent. This is because side effects are allowed: evaluating `f 1` can have observable effects. For instance, `f` could be defined as follows:

```ml
(* Ocaml code *)
let f = let r = ref 0 in
        fun x -> r := !r + x ; !r
```

Using the above definition, `f` has an internal mutable state, which gets incremented by its argument every time it is called, before the new state is returned. Because of this,

```
f 1 + f 1
```

would evaluate to `1 + 2` since the state is incremented twice, while

```
let x = f 1 in x + x
```

would evaluate to `1 + 1`, since only one increment of the state is performed.

The consequence is that, in Ocaml, replacing `x` with its definition would not be a semantics-preserving program transformation. Of course, the same would hold in imperative languages, which allow side effects. Only in pure languages (Haskell, Agda, Coq, ...) the transformation is safe.